# how do you find the last column or row in an excel spreadsheet using python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi am looking to import part of a spreadsheet as a data frame using pandas but the problem is the spreadsheet changes weekly and the number of rows and columns varies each week.

In Excel VBA I can programmatically determine the number of columns and rows in an excel spreadsheet, but how do I determine that in python??

```
col-1 | col -2
1.     blue
2.     green
3.     blue
4.     blank
5.     blank
```

I need some python code preferably a parameter of the python - pandas method read_excel which tells me that the number of columns in the document I pass to it is 2, and the number of rows is 5 or 6 if you include header.

However I need this to be programmable (called each time) because I want to feed it spreadsheets of different sizes with different numbers of columns.

Comment: Are the empty cells really empty or are they string 'blank' or 'NaN'?

Comment: They are blank aka have no data in them. So one spreadsheet may go to 600 rows, but the next week it maybe columns 1-10 woth 7 or 800 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) with method 'ffill'

```
In [71]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,NaN,NaN,4,5,6], 'b':[1,2,NaN,NaN, 3,NaN,4,5]})
df1
Out[71]:
    a   b
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3 NaN
3 NaN NaN
4 NaN   3
5   4 NaN
6   5   4
7   6   5

[8 rows x 2 columns]
```

In [85]:

```
df1.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
df1
Out[85]:
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  2
3  3  2
4  3  3
5  4  3
6  5  4
7  6  5

[8 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Great that's a fantastic way to fill the dataset in where there is missing data.

So much faster than a loop through all the cells in a FOR LOOP using Excel.

Do you know how to find the last used row and column? In the spreadsheets I want to manipulate this varies?

Can you explain more about the Fillna method and the Inplace Parameter. I don't understand what it does based on the documentation. There is almost always no actual use cases sample data input and sample data output in the method documentation.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: `fillna` replaces missing or `NaN `values, the `method` paramter allows for propagating the last valid value forwards or backwards to fill in NaN, `inplace` means that the df is modified setting this to `False` will return a copy

Comment: @user3098818 `xlwt` is a separate module from Pandas, you probably need to install it, I can't help you with that module as I have never used it

Comment: oh I figured it was a dependency of using fillna method. Anyway thanks.